# In tracktion, why is Edit::markAsChanged() not called on midi note changes?

Tags: c++, juce

Edit::markAsChanged() is called for all other modifications like the addition of new tracks or audio clip movements. However, the is not the case for midi note modifications inside a midi clip. Any idea why?

Expecting Edit::markAsChanged() to be called on midi note modifications.
What have I tried? Spelunking in tracktion.